# Getting org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name

Tags: spring

Here is my Controller class. My code is in production and is working. Now, I am on User Story II and trying to make changes. It started to fail Autowiring , so I changed to new OrderService so that instantiation can take place. Now, it is failing and giving me BeanCreationException , so I added PostConstruct init method but I am still getting error.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/order")
public class OrderController {

   private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderController.class);

   OrderDetailsService orderDetailsService = new OrderDetailsService();

   @PostMapping
   public OrderResponse order(@RequestBody(required=false) OrderRequest orderRequest) {
      return orderDetailsService.order(orderRequest);
   }

   @PostConstruct
   public void orderControllerinit() {
          log.debug("orderDetailsService = " + orderDetailsService.toString());
    }  
}
```

Here is the error .

```
rror starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.]
[2020-06-12 16:59:53.644] [ERROR] [Context:SpringApplication] [] [Application run failed]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderController' defined in file [C:\Users\P2932832\BPradhan\SCIAautomation\osm-module\target\classes\com\spectrum\sci\osm\controllers\OrderController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.spectrum.sci.osm.controllers.OrderController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.spectrum.sci.osm.OsmModuleApplication.main(OsmModuleApplication.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.spectrum.sci.osm.controllers.OrderController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1312)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at com.spectrum.sci.osm.service.OrderDetailsService.<init>(OrderDetailsService.java:76)
    at com.spectrum.sci.osm.service.CommonService.<init>(CommonService.java:53)
    at com.spectrum.sci.osm.service.OrderDetailsService.<init>(OrderDetailsService.java:76)
    at com.spectrum.sci.osm.service.CommonService.<init>(CommonService.java:53
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException` isn't a cause, this is final exception in stack, you are seeing, the cause is `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

```sh
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at com.spectrum.sci.osm.service.OrderDetailsService.<init>(OrderDetailsService.java:76)
    at com.spectrum.sci.osm.service.CommonService.<init>(CommonService.java:53)
    at com.spectrum.sci.osm.service.OrderDetailsService.<init>(OrderDetailsService.java:76)
    at com.spectrum.sci.osm.service.CommonService.<init>(CommonService.java:53
```

It seems, that OrderDetailsService creates CommonService, which creates OrderDetailsService, which creates CommonService etc., forming an infinite recursion, which results in `StackOverflowError`.

The number after each class`(CommonService.java:53)` is a row number, find and resolve the recursion.

Comment: This answer helped to resolve the issue.